# GCP metrics for Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine

The GCP docs list two metric APIs: an [old API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-container) and a [new one](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_other#other-kubernetes.io).

I am not seeing any of the newer metrics, but I do see most of the "older" metrics. I have tried version 1.8, 1.10, 1.10 alpha. I have tried giving the instance(s) service account 'owner' permissions. Ive attached permissions to the instances that allow them access these APIs.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue by following these instructions. Im not sure why I did not find this page sooner. I feel like it should be linked to from the metrics page.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing